# Prove that $\sigma$ is a power of $\tau$ when they commute $\sigma\tau=\tau\sigma$.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

> Let $\tau = (1, 2, 3, ..., n)$ be a cycle of maximal length $n$ in the symmetric group $S_n$ and let $\sigma \in S_n$ be such that $\sigma\tau=\tau\sigma$.
>
> Prove that $\sigma$ is a power of $\tau$.

I'm not sure how I can use this fact to prove the claim holds (or doesn't).

Comment: What is $G{}{}$?

Comment: *I think that it is reasonable to assume that $\tau \in Z(G)$ (where $Z(G)$ is the centre of $G$)*.  Sorry, but that isn't reasonable at all.  [The center of a symmetric group is trivial](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Center_of_Symmetric_Group_is_Trivial), so you are assuming that $\tau = e$, which is nonsense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$
as $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, the integers modulo $n$.
Then $\tau$ acts via $\tau(j)\equiv j+1\pmod n$. 
If $\sigma\tau=\tau\sigma$ then
$$\sigma(j+1)\equiv\sigma(j)+1\pmod n$$
and so
$$\sigma(j+k)\equiv\sigma(j)+k\pmod n.$$
Taking $j=n\equiv0\pmod n$ then
$$\sigma(k)\equiv\sigma(n)+k\pmod n$$
so $\sigma=\tau^{\sigma(n)}$.

Comment: I understand up to the final step. How do we move to the final declaration?

Comment: @JoelBiffin $\tau^m(k)\equiv m+k\pmod n$